# Identify the element that is being scrolled to remove properties

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

The sidebar is creating a whitespace and I need to remove its scroll properties. When I expand the sidebar, white space is created below the sidebar. Maybe it is the flex display but other modes of display push the elements below instead of leaving them on the side of the side nav which beats the purpose of the sidenav. **This isssue only occurs on mobile**. the sidebar is scrollable and the items that appear using **ngif** are also scrollable so I do not get the source of the whitespace

```html
<div class="container-fluid rightie">
    <button type="button" id="cart" class="btn btn-link rightee">
        <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <p class="lead">Reap</p>
            <img class="image" id="blah" [src]="imageSrc || '../../../assets/profile.png'" alt="my image" />
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p class="newer" role="button" routerLink="/profile">Username</p>
            <li>
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Produce</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="myproducts" (click)="myproducts()">MyProducts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="addproducts" (click)="addproducts()">Add Products</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Purchase</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmingproduce" (click)="farmingproduce()">Farm Produce</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmingtools" (click)="farmingtools()">Farming Tools</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmingequipment" (click)="farmingequipment()">Farming Equipment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmingchemicals" (click)="farmingchemicals()">Farming Chemicals</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu0" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Farm Orders</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu0">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmpendingorders" (click)="farmpendingorders()">
                           Farm Pending Orders
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmfulfilledorders" (click)="farmfulfilledorders()">
                            Farm Fulfilled Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="farmallorders" (click)="farmallorders()">
                            All Farm Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Orders</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu1">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="pendingorders" (click)="pendingorders()">
                           Pending Orders
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="fulfilledorders" (click)="fulfilledorders()">
                            Fulfilled Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="allorders" (click)="allorders()">
                            All Orders
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pricing</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu2">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="percounty" (click)="percounty()">
                            Per County
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="perproduct" (click)="perproduct()">
                            Per Product
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">About</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu3">
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="aboutus" (click)="aboutus()">
                            About Us
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smaller" id="moreinfo" (click)="moreinfo()">
                            More Info
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg abs">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-outline-light">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 0 || jumbo > 15 || jumbo < 0">
            <app-my-products></app-my-products>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 1">
            <app-add-products></app-add-products>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 2">
            <app-farm-produce></app-farm-produce>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 3">
            <app-farming-tools></app-farming-tools>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 4">
            <app-farming-equipment></app-farming-equipment>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 5">
            <app-farming-chemicals></app-farming-chemicals>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 6">
            <app-farm-pending-orders></app-farm-pending-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 7">
            <app-farm-fulfilled-orders></app-farm-fulfilled-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 8">
            <app-all-farm-orders></app-all-farm-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 9">
            <app-pending-orders></app-pending-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 10">
            <app-fulfilled-orders></app-fulfilled-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 11">
            <app-all-orders></app-all-orders>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 12">
            <app-per-county></app-per-county>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 13">
            <app-per-product></app-per-product>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 14">
            <app-about-us></app-about-us>
        </div>
        <div class="reap" *ngIf="jumbo == 15">
            <app-more-info></app-more-info>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a link for reference,,, this only occurs on mobile 
[element with issue][1]
https://reaphoster.web.app/farmerparent

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.limbo {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
    min-height: 100vh;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filing {
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 40%;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.newer:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
    /* don't forget to add all the previously mentioned styles here too */
    /*background: #7386D5;*/
    color: rgb(146, 145, 145);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 1px;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 1px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555;
}

.fa {
    float: right;
    position: initial;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    /*background: #6d7fcc;*/
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;*/
}

.lead {
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: rgb(146, 145, 145);
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    /*color: #7386D5;*/
    /*background: rgb(121, 172, 238);*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: rgb(146, 145, 145);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
    /*background: #6d7fcc;*/
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    /*background: #6d7fcc;*/
}

#cart {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
}

.rightie {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn {
    color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cbe4d3 0%, #dae4e1 51%, #d7cfe9 100%);
}

.rightee {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.abs {
    position: absolute;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


  [1]: https://reaphoster.web.app/farmerparent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your side navbar position to fixed.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
}
```

#### Also a working example:

```css
nav
{
    position:fixed;
    width: 100px
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    
}

.content
{
    margin: 30px 220px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sidebar fixed</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.iam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametsdiam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```